# Is this Telerik.Web.UI.dll free for use?

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I want to use Telerik.Web.UI.dll but I don't know whether it is free or it needs to pay and were can I download it.
Thank you.

Comment: Its not free, there is a free trial, but you have to pay for it after expiry. You can download it from :http://www.telerik.com/developer-productivity-tools.aspx

Comment: @Habib  
I wanted to know that is there any other option for adding right click context menu for gridview??

Comment: a quick google and found: http://hspharic.blogspot.ca/2007/09/context-menu-in-aspnet-20-gridview.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to buy Telerik Asp.net components to use it, so no, it is not free. Here is the link :
http://www.telerik.com/purchase.aspx

Comment: I wanted to know that is there any other option for adding right click context menu for gridview??

Answer (score 1):

you can download first trial version and if you like it then purchase it. You can download trial version from below link

[trial version](http://www.telerik.com/download.aspx)